# Using Ocean bakes (from Ocean modifier) to Displace a Plane with Geometry Nodes - HOW?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, ocean-simulation

I have created a near-perfect ocean for my scene using texture displacement.  Basically I just made two different ocean bakes and then used them blended together in the displacement channel of my plane.

However, I ran into an issue when I realized that I need Geometry Nodes for the spray effect.  My issue is that I can't figure out how to recreate my ocean with GN, so that I can then use the Ocean Spray bake to create points for the spray geometry.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sspk89pdtju2y7u/GN%20Ocean%20How.zip?dl=0)

This what my material node looks like:

[image]

For this result:

[image]

How would I go about rebuild this node setup in Geometry Nodes?  Take note that I have two different bakes and they are scaled differently, then blended together.

I'm stumped on how to build a GN setup that would have an identical outcome, so that I can further amend the nodes to add Spray.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but perhaps a lead: I'm using the addon "Advanced Ocean Modifier", which uses GeoNodes to add spray. It's a paid addon, but sometimes it's cheaper to buy a setup than to figure it out by yourself :-)

This setup (including more complex material and no/less displacement I think) does render twice as slow as your cached solution over here. And your shader works in a circle, while the Ocean Modifier, basically a layer over the Blender Ocean deformer, uses rectangles. Circle seas give better horizons. But still, perhaps you can inspect their GeoNodes setup.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the tip.  Could you throw me a solid and post a pic of the GN setup that plugin uses for foam?

Comment: Alas: it's an experimental feature and I got a Python error trying to add it in a new document. Foam around objects works though: around floating ones and static objects (like the poles of a peer standing in the water)

Comment: All good man, thanks for trying.  Also, I apologize, I meant SPRAY... foam is pretty easy to manage with baking and material nodes.  I would kill to see the Geonode setup for spray though, if that's possible ;)

Comment: Yes do did I: SPRAY uses GN an throws an error, I just added that FOAM does work. Spray might work in an olde Blender, I’m on 3.3.1

Comment: it's crazy, I cannot find any information about how to create spray, and the documentation about that option is entirely vague in the Blender manual. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: I met the creator of Physical Sky And Starlight at Blender conference this year, he's working on an infinite ocean without tiles...